# Why pass {...props} in a React Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using the route below just because it was the code I found on the web:

```
<Route exact path="/test" render={(props) => <Test {...props} msg={ "abc" } /> } />
```

I know the {...props} denotes multiple arguments but I can't understand why I need it at all because the code below also works just fine and props.msg is available in Test expected

```
<Route exact path="/test" render={() => <Test msg={ "abc" } /> } />
```

So what does {...props} actually do when passed in during render?

Comment: The first snippet passes any *other* matching properties down to `Test`. The second doesn't. Does `Test` have any other properties?

Comment: All `Route` connected props, like history,match etc.see for yourself by `console.log(props)` in `Test`

Comment: `...` is a Javascript feature - the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It *expands* the argument in places where multiple arguments or elements are expected. When used in an object literal, it adds the argument's properties to the new object

Comment: That is passed in case you need other props too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos — The OP says they know what the spread operator does in the question. They want to know why `... props` is being spread into `<Test/>` which can can't know because we have no idea what `<Test/>` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func):

> The render prop function has access to all the same route props (match, location and history) as the component render prop.

If `Test` is not using any of these then you don't have to pass them.

Answer (score 2):

For your use case, your second code snippet is sufficient and will work just fine.

Spreading the props into the child component like

```
<Route exact path="/test" render={(props) => <Test {...props} msg={ "abc" } /> } />
```

makes sense if you want to pass properties to the child component that you are not handling yourself but receiving from another source like the Route-Component itself (in particular the route props "match", "location" and "history").

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind you can have parameters in your route, ex:
/users/:username
Those props will allow you to access it. **In your case, you probably don't need it but you're better to always include them so it's consistent.**

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props

more doc about the 3 props that are provided :

- **match** https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match
- **location** https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location
- **history** https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history